# How to calculate the one particular column total by differentiating items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net, datagridview

I Have a `DataGridView`,  with columns Item, description, quantity, rate & total.
I have two types of items, one item have vapasi == yes (vapasi is a kind of deposite amount), & another item have vapasi == No.I want to calculate the sum of 'total' column by differentiating items with vapasi & items without vapasi, & want to display this calculated total into two respective textboxes that is 'txtboxwithvapasi', n 'txtboxwithoutvapasi' which are there after the grid.I did following code :

```
private void grdPurchase_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            string value = grdPurchase.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
            {
                int val = int.Parse(value);
                quantity = val;
            }
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
            {
                float val = float.Parse(value);
                total = val;

                if (vapasi1 == "Yes")
                {
                    vtot += total; //vtot=0+10

                    txt_forvapasitotal.Text = vtot.ToString(); //10
                    float vapsitot =float.Parse(txt_forvapasitotal.Text);
                    float vapsicalculate = (vapsitot * a);
                    float tax = vapsicalculate / 100;
                    float with_vapasi = vtot + tax;
                    txt_withvapasi.Text =Convert.ToString(with_vapasi);
                }
                else
                {
                    nvtot = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < grdPurchase.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (vapasi1 == "No")
                        {
                            if (grdPurchase.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Selected == true)
                            {
                                nvtot += float.Parse(grdPurchase[4, i].EditedFormattedValue.ToString());
                                txt_withoutvapasitot.Text = nvtot.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              txt_vapasiincludedtot.Text =(float.Parse(txt_withvapasi.Text) +float.Parse(txt_withoutvapasitot.Text)).ToString();
          }
          if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
          {
              int val = int.Parse(value);
              materialid = val;
              string vapasi = "Select material_vapasi from tbl_material_master where active_flag=1 AND material_id =" + materialid + "";
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(vapasi, con);
              sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              if (sdr.HasRows)
              {
                  while (sdr.Read())
                  {
                      vapasi1 = sdr["material_vapasi"].ToString();
                  }
              }
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        grdPurchase.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Problem is:-when I am selecting item with vapasi in first row & in second row item without vapasi , its working properly.But if i Select any item at third row ,then its doing sum of all the three items in 'txtboxwithoutvapasi' without differentiating items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of **vapasi** being "Yes" or "No" for each row in the grid, but you are using a single variable.  Can't you add this column to the grid (as a hidden column if you don't want to show this to the user)?  Then whenever you need to calculate the totals you simply iterate through the grid rows and check the **vapasi column** in stead of the **vapasi1  variable**.